Geometric constructions problems problem book recommendation.
Of all the problems in geometry (proofs, computations, etc.), I liked geometric construction problems the most.
So, I want to ask if there is a problem book dedicated to geometric construction or if there is a book with a whole section for this type of problem.

A : You might want to know about "Possibility theorems" involving Euclidean Constructions & "Impossibility theorems" & Constructing various interesting Patterns & the theoretical background around various types of tools & restrictions , then check out :
"An Investigation of Historical Geometric Constructions"
Authors / Publishers: Suzanne Harper and Shannon Driskell / Mathematical Association of America
[[ https://maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/an-investigation-of-historical-geometric-constructions-introduction ]]
"Geometrical Constructions With Compasses"
Authors / Publishers : Kostovskii / Mir Publishers
[[ https://archive.org/details/kostovskii-geometrical-constructions-with-compasses-only-little-mathematics-library/ ]]
"Geometric Constructions"
Authors / Publishers : George E. Martin / Springer
[[ https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0629-3 ]]
"Geometric Constructions"
Authors / Publishers : Monte Scott Norton / Mcgraw Hill
[[ https://archive.org/details/GeometricConstructions_201806 ]]
B : You might Problems to Solve , maybe with a text book full of geometric construction problems , then check out :
"The Largest Collection of Interactive Geometric Puzzles"
https://www.euclidea.xyz/
IMO & USAMO Problems : https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Category:Geometric_Construction_Problems
"Seventy Constructions in Geometry"
Authors / Publishers : C. Krishna Nambudiri / Arshaprakasam Prasidheekarana Samiti
[[ https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/seventy-constructions-in-geometry-exploring-into-constructional-possibilities-in-geometry-bharatiya-sasthracinta-book-x-ubf287/ ]]
"The Secrets of Triangles"
Authors / Publishers : Alfred S. Posamentier and Ingmar Lehmann / Prometheus
[[ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secrets_of_Triangles ]]
"Geometric Constructions"
Authors / Publishers : Symon Kimitei / Amazon
[[ https://www.amazon.com/GEOMETRIC-CONSTRUCTIONS-Middle-Teachers-Students-ebook/dp/B07Z1J5HCY ]]
Over-all , this list will cover a wide range of topics & difficulty levels.
